# postgres aggregate join matches to an array field

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

I have the following schema + data:

```
create table org_users (
  id character varying (255),
  perdiem_ids character varying (255) --JSONized fk to perdiems.id. example data below
);

create table perdiems (
  id integer,
  name character varying(255)
);

insert into perdiems (id, name) values (1, 'perdiem 1');
insert into perdiems (id, name) values (2, 'perdiem 2');
insert into perdiems (id, name) values (3, 'perdiem 3');

insert into org_users (id, perdiem_ids) values ('user1', '{"allowed_per_diem_ids":[1, 2]}');
insert into org_users (id, perdiem_ids) values ('user2', '{"allowed_per_diem_ids":[2, 3]}');
insert into org_users (id, perdiem_ids) values ('user3', '{"allowed_per_diem_ids":[3, 1]}');
```

Now, I want the list of allowed perdiem names for each org_user, for example, something like:

```
org_user_id | allowed_per_diem_names
------------|---------------------------
user1       | ['perdiem 1', 'perdiem 2']
user2       | ['perdiem 2', 'perdiem 3']
user3       | ['perdiem 3', 'perdiem 1']
```

If I use the following query, I can get the individual user's perdiem names, however the records are duplicated as it is a join.

```
select ou.id, p.name from org_users ou
    left join perdiems p ON p.id = ANY (SELECT json_array_elements(perdiem_ids::JSON->'allowed_per_diem_ids')::text::int from org_users);
```

outputs:

```
| id    | name      |
| ----- | --------- |
| user1 | perdiem 1 |
| user1 | perdiem 2 |
| user1 | perdiem 3 |
| user2 | perdiem 1 |
| user2 | perdiem 2 |
| user2 | perdiem 3 |
| user3 | perdiem 1 |
| user3 | perdiem 2 |
| user3 | perdiem 3 |
```

Now, what is the way to get the records in the formats that I expect ? I want the output of the join operations to become individual elements of an array field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_agg`

```
select ou.id, array_agg(  pd.name  ORDER BY jp.id)
from org_users ou cross join lateral
    json_array_elements_text(((ou.perdiem_ids)::json->'allowed_per_diem_ids')::json)
        with ORDINALITY as jp(perdiem,id) join
      perdiems pd
   on pd.id = jp.perdiem::int
   GROUP BY ou.id;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=616d787330fe75510ca1e715f5b026cd)

Comment: I have accepted the answer since it solves the problem, but is it possible to solve this without using the `GROUP BY` clause on `ou.id` ? Because, I am building a view on top of org_users which has some other fields and hence would require some other joins too (like the allowed_per_diem_ids, I may have fields like, allowed_cost_center_names, allowed_floor_names, etc.) on tables similar to the perdiems (cost_centers, floors, etc.).

Comment: Basically I want to build a view like: `org_user_id (text), perdiem_names (text[]), cost_center_names (text[]), floor_names (text[])` where the individual ids are stored in the org_users table. I just made the question here like this for brevity.

Comment: @Sankar : You may ask that as a separate question. I believe this answers your original question.

Comment: Done. Asked it as a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305373/postgres-aggregate-join-matches-to-multiple-array-fields-while-creating-views  with some more details and a bit changed schema structure to explain the problem even more precisely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you there:

```
select *
from org_users ou cross join lateral
     json_array_elements_text(((ou.perdiem_ids)::json->'allowed_per_diem_ids')::json) ou_id join
     perdiems pd
     on pd.id = ou_id::int;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=79501673e876d5fa424facee12e91ada) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This still returns duplicate records. I want only one row for each org_user.