# postgres aggregate join matches to multiple array fields while creating views

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

I have the following schema + data:

```
create table org_users (
  id character varying (255),
  settings_id character varying (255) -- fk: settings.id
);

create table settings (
  id character varying (255), -- primary key settings_id
  perdiem_settings character varying (255), -- jsonised fk to perdiems.id
  floor_settings character varying (255) -- jsonised fk to floors.id
);

create table perdiems (
  id integer, -- primary key
  name character varying(255)
);

create table floors (
  id integer, -- primary key
  name character varying (255)
);

insert into perdiems (id, name) values (1, 'perdiem 1');
insert into perdiems (id, name) values (2, 'perdiem 2');
insert into perdiems (id, name) values (3, 'perdiem 3');

insert into floors (id, name) values (1, 'floor 1');
insert into floors (id, name) values (2, 'floor 2');
insert into floors (id, name) values (3, 'floor 3');

insert into settings (id, perdiem_settings, floor_settings) values ('setting1', '{"allowed_per_diem_ids":[1, 2]}', '{"allowed_floor_ids":[1]}');
insert into settings (id, perdiem_settings, floor_settings) values ('setting2', '{"allowed_per_diem_ids":[2, 3]}', '{"allowed_floor_ids":[1, 2]}');
insert into settings (id, perdiem_settings, floor_settings) values ('setting3', '{"allowed_per_diem_ids":[3, 1]}', '{"allowed_floor_ids":[1, 2, 3]}');

insert into org_users (id, settings_id) values ('user1', 'setting1');
insert into org_users (id, settings_id) values ('user2', 'setting2');
insert into org_users (id, settings_id) values ('user3', 'setting3');
```

Now I want to create a view which will have aggregates from each of the other table, into an array field of its own. To explain with an example, the view that I want should be like:

```
org_user_id | settings_id | perdiems                   | floors
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user1       | setting1    | ['perdiem 1', 'perdiem 2'] | ['floor 1']
user2       | setting2    | ['perdiem 2', 'perdiem 3'] | ['floor 1', 'floor 2']
user3       | setting3    | ['perdiem 3', 'perdiem 1'] | ['floor 1', 'floor 2', 'floor 3']
```

This question is somewhat related to [postgres aggregate join matches to an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299226/postgres-aggregate-join-matches-to-an-array-field) which deals with creating array fields out of join matches. However, here I want to create multiple array fields in a single view and so using a `GROUP BY` clause will not be feasible iiuc.

The query that I tried is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_settings_view AS
 SELECT ou.id AS org_user_id, <other fields...>
    FROM org_users ou
     LEFT JOIN settings pdr_s ON pdr_s.id = ou.settings_id
     LEFT JOIN perdiems pdr ON pdr.id = ANY (SELECT json_array_elements(perdiem_settings::JSON->'allowed_per_diem_ids')::text::int FROM settings)
```

which creates duplicate records for each of the matching perdiem because of the join and not creating an array. Even if I crate an array as mentioned in the other stackoverflow question, it won't work if I have multiple string arrays as part of the view for different columns. Any way I can get multiple join matches to multiple array fields in a single view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the result.

```
select ou.id, array_agg( DISTINCT pd.name  ),
              array_agg( DISTINCT f.name   )
from org_users ou join settings s on  ou.settings_id = s.id
 cross join lateral
    json_array_elements_text(((s.perdiem_settings)::json->'allowed_per_diem_ids')::json)
       as jp(perdiem) join
      perdiems pd    
   on pd.id = jp.perdiem::int
  cross join lateral
    json_array_elements_text(((s.floor_settings)::json->'allowed_floor_ids')::json)
        as js(floor) join
      floors f
   on f.id = js.floor::int
   GROUP BY ou.id;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e711e955493624860239030304c44bdf)

**Edit**

For cases of `NULL` settings, you may use a separate `UNION ALL`

```
select id , ARRAY[NULL] as perdiems ,ARRAY[NULL] as floors FROM org_users 
WHERE settings_id IS NULL 
 UNION ALL
(
   -- The above query --
 ) ORDER BY id;
```

[**Demo2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b7e27e66ad025de155f03a6bb7fa5564)

Comment: this works. However, this fails to execute when there are records with null values. A user could have null settings, A setting could be null for either perdiem or floor. For example: `insert into org_users (id, settings_id) values ('user4', null)` does not return the `user4` in the final output.

Comment: @Sankar :  you may use `Left joins` instead of inner  join. I was just using your sample that's all.

Comment: +Kaushik  : Even if I change the `from org_users ou join settings s on` to `from org_users ou left join settings s on` I am not able to see the `user4`.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b55454b20e88a5cb3dbb6fe3b6270b91 is the url. Or do I misunderstand which join you refer to ?

Comment: @Sankar : it may require a null check. I'm responding from my app now, will take a look and edit a while later. you may try with some options though

Comment: @Sankar : It seems a lot of changes would be required in the joins to handle the `NULL` case especially due to the fact that `json`  also returns null. This may hamper the performance for large rows. So, I would suggest a simpler approach using `UNION ALL`   See  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b7e27e66ad025de155f03a6bb7fa5564

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check with some more cases tomorrow and will confirm the query. May be you could add this also as part of the answer so that it would help others too. I will confirm after testing more corner cases. Thanks once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183756/discussion-between-sankar-and-kaushik-nayak).